# Wordpress Post Thumbnail invalid url for Discord webhook

Tags: php, wordpress, discord, webhooks

I'm trying to post a message on a discord server when a new post is published using webhooks, it works fine until I try to add the post's thumbnail, when I put a string with the url it works fine  but whenever i replace that with my var it doesn't work

```
$webhookURL = get_option('discord_webhook_url');
$id = $post->ID;
$postTitle = get_the_title($id);
$image_url =get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id);
$permalink =get_permalink($id);
$message = "@everyone Test";

$hookObject = json_encode([
    /*
     * The general "message" shown above your embeds
     */
    "content" => $message,
    /*
     * An array of Embeds
     */
    "embeds" => [
        /*
         * Our first embed
         */
        [
            // Set the title for your embed
            "title" => $postTitle,

            // A description for your embed
            "description" => "test embed",

            // The URL of where your title will be a link to
            "url" => $permalink,

            // The integer color to be used on the left side of the embed
            "color" => hexdec( "5814783" ),

            // Image object
            "image" => [
                "url" => $image_url,
            ],
        ]
    ]

], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
$headers = [ 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' ];
$curl = curl_init($webhookURL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $hookObject);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

So for instance when I replace

```
                "image" => [
                "url" => $image_url,
            ],
```

With

```
                "image" => [
                "url" => "path-to-thumbnail.jpg",
            ],
```

It works just fine.

The best lead I found is this thread [In my discord webhook, I am getting the error: {"embeds": ["0"]}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935198/in-my-discord-webhook-i-am-getting-the-error-embeds-0) suggesting that the URL is invalid, and I checked my logs I do have the embed["0"] just like the original question.

Any idea why ?

Edit : After some digging I found out that the `has_post_thumbnail` returns false however I did setup a featured image / thumbnail on my post

Comment: What is $image_url returning? Have you tried to log it?

Comment: Returns nothing in the logs, but i don't know why, the post url and post title is returning the right values

Comment: What is the scope you are trying to call it via? Have you tried running your script on a clean install of WordPress (to remove plugin and theme intervention), does it not show up either?